# Plone: How to check when was a user created and by whom?

Tags: plone

I am trying to find out the user creation time and the person who created it. I am trying to get these from user properties, but could not find anything.

```
acl = getToolByName(self.context,'acl_users')
userObject = acl.getUserById('userId')
x = userObject._propertysheets.values()[0]
pp xy.propertyItems()
```

The result is:

```
[('email', 'user@user.com'),
('portal_skin', ''),
('listed', True),
('login_time', DateTime('2012/03/08 10:43:53.299987 GMT')),
('last_login_time', DateTime('2012/01/23 12:56:33.343882 GMT')),
('fullname', u'user'),
('error_log_update', 0.0),
('home_page', ''),
('location', ''),
('description', ''),
('language', ''),
('ext_editor', False),
('wysiwyg_editor', ''),
('visible_ids', False)]
```

It does not contain user creation time. So I am wondering if Plone records this information at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That information is not available; you'd have to customize the registration process to add that data.

Your other option is to implement members as content (using `membrane`) at which point the usual Plone content fields for `.Creator()` and `.created()` will work.

Answer (score -3):

If you get the member object, you can call the CreationDate Dublin Core method on it to get this information.

```
return userObject.CreationDate()
```

To get the creator, you can similarly call 'Creator'. This may return None if the user was created programmatically.

Comment: No, the creation date and creator returned by these methods are of the Membership tool, not of the member data objects themselves. You are looking at acquired methods!

Comment: @tman: sorry, but the data you'll get will be the same for *every* user, and it's the date and creator of the portal_membership tool. In other words, you are acquiring the methods from the acquisition chain (they are not defined on member data objects) and thus getting non-local information.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, I noticed it, but it does not really matter since I can acquire the method without any problem, I just want the date. Thanks for reminding me this though.

Comment: Sorry @tman but this doesn't make sense with your actual question: if you are ok to have the creation date of the portal tool (which probably is the date when you created your plone site) then your question doesn't match with this answer (and viceversa).

Comment: @tman: the method returns the creation date for the tool, *not* the users. Acquiring the method does not mean it'll return the correct value for the user object!

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah, sorry I misunderstood what you meant. The date and the creator are all the same for every user I checked. Thanks.

Comment: @MartjinPieters the CreationDate method works for a normal user object in Plone 4. Tested by comparison with user.aq_parent.CreationDate(). Creator does not appear to work though, as you say.